# How to render FORTRAN-style overprinting in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, printing

[In FORTRAN](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch2-14.html), one is able to request printing of a line over the previous line. When printing on legacy line printers, this mechanism could be used for many purposes, from imitating characters not present in the charset of the printer, e.g. / over = for ≠, to grayscale shading for ASCII art.

What is the most efficient and reliable way to express that a line should overprint the previous line in HTML/CSS, ideally a custom tag which is to "carriage return" as <br> is to "line feed"? Obviously, this will be used only within a <pre> tag.

Update: Tagging overprinted lines as "line-height: 0" within a <pre> tag results in [inconsistent line spacing](http://jsbin.com/suxukeximo/edit?html,css,output).

CSS:

```
div { line-height: 0; }
```

HTML:

```
<pre><div>XXXX<br>----<br>||||</div><br>XXXX<br>YYYY</pre>
```

(Previously asked in RetroComputing, sent here.)

Answer (score 1):

[The best I've got so far](http://jsbin.com/moxulonufo/edit?html,css,output) is
CSS:

```
.over {
    line-height: 0;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: -0.5em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<pre>
FIRST LINE
PREVIOUS LINE
<div class="over">GOOD BYE
XXXX XXX HELLO WORLD</div>
NEXT LINE
LAST LINE
</pre>
```

However, this is close, but still no cigar (0.6em and -0.6em look slightly better [because the default value of line-height is not 1 but "roughly 1.2"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)). The right way would be to mark each **overprinting** line with a tag

```
.over { margin-top: -MAGIC; margin-bottom: -MAGIC; }
```

and to have in HTML

```
<pre>FIRST LINE
PREVIOUS LINE
GOOD BYE
<div class=over>XXXX XXX HELLO WORLD</div>
NEXT LINE
LAST LINE</pre>
```

where MAGIC should be equal to 'line-height'. "1em" refers to 'font-size' and by default is slightly less than necessary. The line-height property is itself magic in the sense that it allows unit-less values with a special meaning, and for the margin attributes a unit-less value means "pixels".

Answer (score 0):

well try this

```
.element {
line-height: 0; }
```

i made this
http://jsbin.com/secawarizi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks. This is efficient but, unfortunately, not reliable. With a `<div>` tag defined this way **without pixel-level formatting** `<pre><div>XXXX<br>----</div><br>XXXX<br>YYYY</pre>` results in inconsistent line spacing. (see the edit on jsbin)